# Build a public archive of emails/newsletters

Tags: email, self-hosted, web-server, mailing-list

I'm looking to build a public archive of emails from various mailing lists. I'd like to be able to run a mail server that can receive emails and make them publicly accessible through a web interface. Then I would just take the email address of the mail server and sign it up for a bunch of mailing lists, and those emails would automatically become public. Can anyone recommend a mail server that supports something like this?